# Unique solution to a specific Volterra's integral equation of the third kind

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems, integral-equations

Consider an integral equation (Volterra's integral equation of the third kind)
$$(d-cx) u(x) = \int_x^b u(y) dy, \qquad x \in [a,b] \qquad (1) $$
where $u:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is an unknown function and $a,b,c,$ and $d$ are (non-negative) constants such that $d = cb$ (that is, function $d - cx$ vanishes at $x=b$).

It is straightforward to verify that
$$ u(x) = h_1 (d-cx)^{\frac{1-c}{c}}, $$
for any constant $h_1$ is a solution to (1). Is this the **unique** solution?

Comment: This is what I've tried this far.

If we assume that $u\in L^1([a,b])$, then for $U(x)=\int_x^b u(y)dy$ we have $U'(x) = -u(x)$ for almost every $x\in[a,b]$ (see, e.g., Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd edition, Theorem 7.11). Then we can write (1) as the following differential equation
$$ -(d-cx)U'(x) = U(x), \qquad a.e. $$
Does this have a unique solution?

Comment: We have $\frac{d}{dx}\left((d-c x)u(x)\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\int_b^x u(y)dy\right)$ almost everywhere and the solution to this ode is $u(x) = c_0(d-c x)^{\frac{1-c}{c}}$

Comment: Thanks for your comment Cesareo. Is that the unique solution? And do we need to assume differentiability of $u$ for that?